# Wander algorithm for a maze

Tags: 3d, ai, path-finding, steering-behaviors

I am making a multiplayer coop FPS game. I have created the first monster with it's AI. I have worked out the A* algorithm for the level based on the triangles of the walkable mesh.
So I can already find a path from point A to point B in the level. The question is, how would I implement a random wander algorithm?

The simple wander and evade obstacle steering behavior will not do, I think. I probably need to use the Path finding data.

What kind of algorithm do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this seems to be to simply generate a random point on the mesh and walk to it. You can restrict the point to be within a radius of the monster's position in order to avoid really long random walks too.